# Scala variable names collected into List of String

Tags: scala, reflection

For any given function, for instance,

```
  def f(i: Int) = {
    val x = i * i
    val y = x + x
    val result = y+x
    result
  }
```

how to obtain the names of the variables into

```
List[String]("x","y","result")
```

Comment: why some need to store the name of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inspect variable names in Scala. You can reflect on types and on packages, but not on function bodies (and local variable names are not available in class files anyway).

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: No. It is not possible to implement such a package. The local variable names do not exist anywhere either in the compiled program or at runtime. Something which does not exist cannot be accessed. Not even by using a include (whatever the heck that is).